# Can't type passwords in terminal

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, root

I have been trying to do sudo commands inside the Ubuntu terminal and I have 2 issues...

Issue #1: I cannot type in the terminal when it asks for a password.

Issue #2: I never even had set a sudo password before. Is there a default one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal does not show anything when you type your password. This is for security purposes. Simply type your password and hit enter.

Your `sudo` password is your user password. The "default" is whatever password you use to log in. If there was a default password, Ubuntu would be extremely insecure, so we don't do that.

Comment: @SalemAnderson once you're able to, would you mind accepting this answer (checkmark below voting arrows on the left)? It helps others to know that something worked for you.

Comment: I will, it says I need to wait another 6minutes to be able to

Comment: @SalemAnderson yep. That's to prevent accepting an answer that may not be very good (give others a chance to write more in-depth answers). If someone writes an answer with more explanation than mine, then they have time to do so, and you can then choose the better answer. Thanks :).

Comment: Now the issue is with the company I've paid 105$ for their product that doesn't seem to be working. Has their been similar questions involving VPNs? I know you can't do anything if it's with another company (AirVPN) but if you have any tips I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can ask another question and include specifics. It might not be on-topic, but I can't tell from what you've given me.

Comment: @SalemAnderson My tip is to keep coming to AskUbuntu every day and reading questions and answers. Those that make your eyes glaze over simply skip over and the others that make you think "me too" read them and learn more. Virtual Private Networks (VPN) makes my eyes glaze over so I skip them.